# Filtering by column values using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a data frame of dates in pandas and I want to filter it such that 'date_id' is between 'start_date' and 'end_date'

```
     date_id    start_date  end_date
0   2010-06-04  2008-08-01  2008-09-26
1   2010-06-04  2008-08-01  2008-09-26
2   2010-06-04  2008-08-01  2008-09-26
3   2010-06-04  2008-08-26  2008-10-26
4   2010-06-04  2010-05-01  2010-09-26
5   2010-06-04  2008-08-01  2008-09-26
6   2010-06-04  2008-08-01  2008-09-26
7   2010-09-04  2010-08-01  2010-09-26
```

I've tried using the code below:

```
df[(df['date_id'] >= df['start_date'] & df['date_id']<= df['end_date')]
```

The code above results in a key error. I am a new pandas user so any assistance/documentation would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [between](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.between.html)!

```
df['date_id'].between(df['start_date'],df['end_date_y'])
```

and to filter, just use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.loc[df['date_id'].between(df['start_date'],df['end_date_y'])]


     date_id start_date end_date_y
4 2010-06-04 2010-05-01 2010-09-26
7 2010-09-04 2010-08-01 2010-09-26
```

Comment: Also in my answer.

Comment: I was working on the solution before you posted it I guess! good work

Answer (score 1):

I think need change column name to `end_date_y` and add `()` because operator precedence:

```
df1 = df[(df['date_id'] >= df['start_date']) & (df['date_id']<= df['end_date_y'])]
```

Or use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df1 = df[df['date_id'].between(df['start_date'], df['end_date_y'])]
print (df1)
     date_id start_date end_date_y
4 2010-06-04 2010-05-01 2010-09-26
7 2010-09-04 2010-08-01 2010-09-26
```

**Performance**:

Depends of number of rows and number of matched rows, so the best test in real data.

```
#[80000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
#print (df)

In [236]: %timeit df[df['date_id'].between(df['start_date'], df['end_date_y'])]
2.44 ms ± 92.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [237]: %timeit df[(df['date_id'] >= df['start_date']) & (df['date_id']<= df['end_date_y'])]
2.42 ms ± 193 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [238]: %timeit df.query("start_date <= date_id <=  end_date_y")
4.45 ms ± 14.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) as:

```
df.query("start_date <= date_id <=  end_date_y")

    date_id     start_date  end_date_y
4   2010-06-04  2010-05-01  2010-09-26
7   2010-09-04  2010-08-01  2010-09-26
```